# Using esellerate SDK in xcode problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

I'm trying to use the Esellerate SDK in my cocoa application, i dragged the "EWSMac.framework" to the frameworks folder in xcode 4. But when compiling i get:

```
ld: framework not found EWSMac
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Theres not much documentation on the subject in the esellerate SDK DMG.

Please help

Comment: What have you tried? How exactly have you added this framework to your project and set it up in your target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the EWSMac.framework was never meant to be linked against in your application - it's loaded dynamically at runtime by the libEWS.a static library. Try removing this engine, adding the compressed one to your project, and linking against the libEWS.a file (which gives you all of the entry points into the SDK). Strange, I know, but this was done due to a security model that encrypts the binary in the framework, only allowing it to be called from their static library.